# how can i handle class imbalance from different data sets?

Tags: classification, sampling, unbalanced-classes

I have an imbalanced problem and my datasets are from 4 different countries; 1 of these countries has % of cancer patients at 2%, the rest are at 1%.

When i ran a training job using xgboost it seemed to be learning more from the country with 2%. It wasn't learning anything from the countries where we have less.

The sampling technique used was to 'stratify by country' where the % of cancer patients was kept the same per country. Then this data was combined as the final training set.

how else can i deal with getting a training set? i am thinking of doing the following instead:

- over sample minority class in the 3 countries with 1% to take it up to 2%
- then for each of the 3 countries under sample majority class to make it equal to minority
- for the country with 2%, undersample to make equal with non cancer patients numbers
- combine all 4 contries data for final training set

does the above seem ok ? how else can i do this, or should i combine all datasets together irrespective of country they are from and oversample and under sample?

```
# instantiating over and under sampler
X= all_country_data
y = label
over = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.8)
# first performing oversampling to minority class
X_over, y_over = over.fit_resample(X, y)
print(f"Oversampled: {Counter(y_over)}")
Oversampled: Counter({0: 9844, 1: 4922})
# now to comine under sampling 
X_combined_sampling, y_combined_sampling = under.fit_resample(X_over, y_over)
print(f"Combined Random Sampling: {Counter(y_combined_sampling)}")
Combined Random Sampling: Counter({0: 6152, 1: 4922})
```

Comment: What about the imbalanced classes strikes you as so problematic?

Comment: Hi Dave, it is because when I train then validate the model the predictions on country 1 are different to the other 3 when validated using the out of sample test.